# How to use results of a background thread database query in the main thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-room

The situation is, from the main thread, I want to pass some data to a background database thread. This background thread selects some things from the database, combines it with the data, and stores it to the database.

Then I want the main thread to access this newly saved data (because it is now enriched) and display the results to the user.

I have thought of a very simple way. (Is there anything wrong with this?)

From my background thread, I simply post a runnable containing the enriched object to my main thread's handler?

I think this will create a happens-before event (since the new thread will have up-to-date data?).

So in summary, the main thread posts a runnable to the background thread handler, and in that runnable, when its work is done, it posts a runnable back to the main thread handler, where work continues?

It seems too simple, like I might be missing something...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it's not good approach
Consider this:
create a suspend function for select data from database and with Coroutines and Flow query on background and collect the new data in main thread
for using this approach you have to know how to work with Kotlin Flow,ViewModels,Kotlin Coroutines.

If you are using Room db you can check out this Google code lab:
[google flow and coroutine code lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/?text=room%20flow)

Comment: Thanks, would you mind elaborating on what you don't like about it? I just coded it in about 2 minutes and it seems to work fine..

Comment: At first with runnable you lock a thread . Second coroutines are lightweight threads and are more efficient than using a thread.
Last reason is using the approach I mentioned is Google best practice in modern android development.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by lock a thread? I'm using handlers with loopers for each thread, so first from the main thread I place a runnable on the background's request queue. Then when that executes and has finished its work, it places a runnable on the main thread's request queue. No threads are locked - the looper is working through the runnables in its queue and executes my runnables when it gets to them..

Comment: you are right .
I mean consuming resources is not optimized using threads.

Comment: I will definitely look into what you're saying though - and thanks for the suggestion. I'm not trying to disregard it, just trying to get this done quickly and if there's no major downside, I'm tempted to go with something that won't require me to learn a lot of new things.

Comment: You are welcome.
I hope my answer helps you.

Comment: Ah ok - thank you. So what I'm hearing is that it's definitely not great, because there's much more elegant and efficient ways of doing it. However, it's not expected to break anything or cause memory leaks or anything nasty that I need to worry about too much. Sorry to be a luddite....

Comment: I am happy for talking to you.
Good luck.